# Eclipse with Dandelion Plugin: Error on Evaluation of LISP Programs on Debian

Tags: eclipse, lisp, common-lisp

I decided to start learning LISP within Eclipse on Debian, so I installed the Dandelion extension. However, when I tried to evaluate any program, it throws the two errors shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1i8li.jpg).

I can't make sense of why it would be giving a *java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused* error. Originally I had three errors, but after making my */...environment_clisp_2.49.2* an executable, that took care of the third one.

If anyone has experience with coding with LISP on Eclipse and could help me out with getting my IDE configured, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I expect that you need to have a Lisp running somewhere with a socket that you can connect to.  That's how SLIME in Emacs works, for instance.   That'd be my guess in a seeing a ConnectException.

Comment: First of all: Verify that CLISP is running correctly. Can you start its REPL? (Btw where did you get/download it from?)

Comment: @DanielJour I attempted to run CLISP in Terminal, but the _clisp_ command wasn't found, so I ran _sudo apt-get install clisp_, and it came up with this:

_Package clisp is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'clisp' has no installation candidate_

Comment: Try to run the file that you made executable. Your Debian has no clisp ... That's strange!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Dandelion is rather old and it seems o be impossible to connect the plugin to a recent SBCL etc. using Swank. The Swank client included in Dandelion is too old to be able to connect to the up-to-date Swank servers included with the current distributions.

Anyway - look inside the Dandelion plugins directory, probably somewhere in your ~/.eclipse folder. There should be a (older) SBCL and Clisp distribution included in the plugins subfolders. You need to find the binary fitting to your platform and check, if that is working. That directory is surely not part of your PATH variable. There is a chance that Dandelion will work with these included distros, as in these environments the Swank server and client fit together.

Although I really like the idea of the Lisp plugin for Eclipse and Dandelion seems to be very promising, I never made it to work reliably. So I switched back to Emacs, unfortunately.

IMHO the biggest problem of Common Lisp in gaining a bigger audience nowadays is the lack of a good, standard development environment. People are used to Eclipse and assorted IDEs, in case they are tired of Java and look for something more dynamic, there would be a good chance that they try CL. But as they have to use Emacs to work with CL, they will use Clojure instead, as this has the standard IDE support. People want to spend their efforts in learning new languages, not new/old editors.